# In Python, can I specify a range of string indices in a return statement placeholder?

Tags: python, indexing, format, slice, placeholder

I'm practising using Python's .format method.

The first block of code below can print `first_name` and the first letter of `last_name`.

In the second block of code I was experimenting with the index in the second place holder to try and specify a slice of letters to print.

However, I can't get it to work. Is this possible?

```
def nametag(first_name, last_name):
    return("{} {[0]}.".format(first_name, last_name))

print(nametag("Joe", "Smith")) 
print(nametag("Frank", "Rinaldi")) 
print(nametag("Jean-Luc", "Pierre"))
```

```
def nametag(first_name, last_name):
    return("{} {[0:3]}.".format(first_name, last_name))

print(nametag("Joe", "Smith")) 
print(nametag("Frank", "Rinaldi")) 
print(nametag("Jean-Luc", "Pierre"))
```

Comment: one sure way is to do `return '{} {}'.format(first_name, last_name[0:3])`, but also I would suggest that you use `f` strings (Python 3.6+) instead as they are better (easier to read/understand, faster), in which case it would be `return f'{first_name} {last_name[0:3]}'`

Comment: @Matiiss Works perfectly. Yes, f-strings work better for the reasons you said. Thank you!

Comment: Based on https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#grammar-token-format-string-element_index it is not possible with "format" function and @Matiiss comment is the best answer :)

Comment: @AmirrezaNoori thanks for the confirmation. Appreciated. :)